# viso2 stereo disparity

Tags: calibration, viso2-ros, viso2, libviso2, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros) . So I calibrated my stereo camera set.[image: image description]

Does the distance between the cameras matter much?Is this setup good enough?

[image: image description] [image: image description]

The above are my calibration results.Is that fine? I didn't get any reprojection error as mention in this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/202647/pose-going-up-and-constant-visual-odometry-got-lost-message/). It just showed `?` under `epi` . Is that okay.Around 180 samples were used in calibration.

Then I used `stereo_image_proc` package and then tried to optimize the [parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters)

[image: image description]

A few more disparity maps [image: image description]

Are the disparity maps ok? Any suggestions on improving them? Is it okay to have grey background?

The following is the tf and rqt_graph [image: image description]
[image: image description]

Is that correct? My knowledge on tf is basic and limited as I am a beginner. The following is the launch file used to generate the tf tree.

[image: image description]

cambase is nothing but the left camera as suggested in this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/63071/viso2-camera-configuration/).

I also checked the `~info` topic messages of stereo odometer. the number of inlier's is very low i.e less than 10 and the number of matches is at max 25 . How do I improve upon it? I am always getting

```
Visual Odometer got lost!
```

even when the setup is at rest. How do I improve the inliers and get my system running? Are the things setup till now correct like the calibration and tf tree.

Configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

ROS distro: Hydro

Camera: [PS3 eyecamera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Eye) X 2  ----  640x480 @ 60fps

P.S: If anything is not clear please let me know. This my first post. I have also read the following posts before asking and tried to improve from those suggestions

1. [Post 1](http://answers.ros.org/question/119921/problem-with-viso2-visual-odometer-got-lost/)
2. [Post 2](http://answers.ros.org/question/62872/viso2_ros-shows-visual-odometer-got-lost/)
3. [Post 3](http://answers.ros.org/question/202647/pose-going-up-and-constant-visual-odometry-got-lost-message/)
4. [Post 4](http://answers.ros.org/question/63071/viso2-camera-configuration/)

Update:

Point cloud generated by running `viso2` . It is just some dots behind the camera.

[image: image description]

point cloud generated by `stereo_image_proc`

[image: image description]

This is the output of `rostopic echo /stereo/left/camera_info` and `rostopic echo /stereo/right/camera_info` . I hope it is correct to compare to `seq` with same id.
[image: image description]

Also my stereo set is running at 640x480 @ 60fps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209955/viso2-stereo-disparity/) by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

> Does the distance between the cameras matter much?

Yes it does matte, as you increase the baselength B, your ability to reconstruct distant points increases, for indoor purposes baseline should be around ~12/13 cm. (this depends on the camera lenses(zoom level) and the focal length too). for out-door purposes use 25 to 30 cm.

> Is this setup good enough?

the set up is good enough. make sure that cameras provide data of the same time, i mean there should not me more 30ms of delay between two camera(left-right) frames(again this depends on your speed of camera)

> The above are my calibration results.Is that fine?

Your calibration looks fine! and disparity map too.

> Are the disparity maps ok? Any suggestions on improving them? Is it okay to have grey background?

You are getting grey parts in back ground because algorithm is not able to find the disparity values for that region. if you want to improve it, you should use SGBM (again speed is the deciding factor here)

> I didn't get any reprojection error as mention in this post. It just showed ? under epi . Is that okay.Around 180 samples were used in calibration.

After the calibration, when you bring your board in the frame the '?' will be replaced by the reprojection error. Try it again :) and 180 samples are more than enough. usually 20 samples will do the job :P

> > > Now the actual question,

Viso2 is very good algorithm for pose estimation, it computes sparse features to get the changes in pose, the code is meant for high resolution and wide-baseline cameras and for out door purposes, though it should work on the low resolution cameras too. Your TF tree and other system level things are fine as far as i can see but the code is not able to find sufficient amount of feature matches thats  the reason for "odom lost".

Try running this package outdoor and see how is the performance once. Number of matches will improve. Make sure that you experiment with this package in an environment where number of features are high. Try not to perform in-place rotation of camera, in that case Visual odometry algorithm might not work properly.

Hope I helped
Sudeep

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2015-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-06-02**:
Thanks. I am working the on things you suggested.I kept `approximate_sync:=true` for the `stereo_image_proc` node.I used `rostopic echo /stereo/left/camera_info` and `rostopic echo /stereo/right/camera_info` and matched the `seq` to get time stamps. I hope that's correct way.Updated question

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-06-02**:
Also I have kept my `min_disparity:= -128` and `disparity_range:=128` to have maximum range. Should I be optimizing on that ?[Computation cost is not a problem for me at the moment.]

**Comment by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) on 2015-06-03**:
@^^ if you are not planning to mount the stereo camera on some fast moving robot like car then approximate_sync is fine. put min disparity as 0 and range as 128. To get better disparity use SGBM algorithm instead of BM(the one you are currently using) this will give you dense reconstruction.

**Comment by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) on 2015-06-03**:
But it will not improve the performance of VISO2. Viso2 computes its own sparse feature based correspondence. :P

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-06-03**:
Ok. I realised that the point cloud generated by viso2 is very sparse. Also I see that even-though my setup is at rest there is  movement in rviz. Also observed that point cloud generated by `viso2` is in -ve z- direction where as the pointcloud generated by `stereo_image_proc` is in +ve z-direction

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-06-03**:
Is that normal? I am also adding the point-cloud generated by `viso2` and `stereo_image_proc`